# How do i add color into a nested letter

Tags: css, sass

How to add black color to all the ampersands. I tried `span::first-letter` but it doesn't apply. I'm basically trying to nest them in scss.

```
<div class="all-cakes">
  <p class="cake">
    <span class = "chocolate"> Chocolate </span>
    <span class = "nuts"> & nuts </span> 
    <span class = "raisins"> & raisins</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

scss:

```
$cakeColor: gold;
$chocolate: brown;
$nut: goldenRod;
$raisins: darkGoldenRod;



.all-cakes{

  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;

  .cake {

    & > span{
      font-size: 40px;

      span::first-letter{
        color: black;
      }

      &:nth-child(1){
        color: $chocolate;
      }


      &:nth-child(2){
       color: $nut;
      }


      &:nth-child(3){
       color: $raisins;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `span::first-letter` it should be `&::first-letter` I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::first-letter` [doesn't work on inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter). So we must use `display:inline-block;`  or `display:block;` on `span` or use `p` or any other block level element instead of `span`.
But even if we use first-letter on block level elements it seems that it excludes non-word characters like `@!=&%` and so on. But that isn't consistent among all browsers.

So I would generate the ampersands with `:before{content:"&";color:black;}` instead.

```css
$cakeColor: gold;
$chocolate: brown;
$nut: goldenRod;
$raisins: darkGoldenRod;



.all-cakes{

  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;

  .cake {

    & > span{
      font-size: 40px;

      &:nth-child(1){
        color: $chocolate;
      }


      &:nth-child(2){
       color: $nut;
      }

      &:nth-child(2):before {
         content: "&";
         color: black;
      }
      &:nth-child(3){
       color: $raisins;
      }
      &:nth-child(3):before {
         content: "&";
         color: black;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested)

```
 span {

      font-size: 40px;

      &:first-letter {
         color: black;
      }
}
```